# C# Chart Y interval line missing after zoom

Tags: c#, charts, intervals, yaxis

I have still have a problem with C# Chart (in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace).
When i zoom on Y axis, sometimes, interval line aren't redrawn.
Look at the picture below, interval lines are missing under 0.[Missing interval line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve7tV.png)

Usually, there is no problem and 11 interval lines are drawn.

```
        private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e != null) && (sender != null))
        {
            // on ne récupère que les évènement concernant l'axe Y. L'axe X se gère tout seul car il est unique
            if (e.Axis.AxisName.ToString() == "Y")
            {
                // AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum is the minimum Y axis value displayed. It contains the offset to apply to label, grid and interval on Y axis
                e.ChartArea.AxisY.IntervalOffset = (e.ChartArea.AxisY.Interval - e.ChartArea.AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum) % e.ChartArea.AxisY.Interval;

                // To update Y axis label, major grid and interval. 
                e.ChartArea.AxisY.Interval = (e.ChartArea.AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum - e.ChartArea.AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum) / 11;

            }
        }
    }
```

Above is my axisViewChanged event.

The Y axis is declared as below

```
chartArea1.AxisY.Interval = (sens.dMaximumValue - sens.dMinimumValue)/11.0;
        chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
        chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = ".000";
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White; // Color.DarkViolet;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Maximum = sens.dMaximumValue*1.1;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Minimum = sens.dMinimumValue*1.1;
        chartArea1.AxisY.ScaleView.MinSize = 0.01D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0.001D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.ScrollBar.BackColor = Color.White;
        chartArea1.AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.LightGray;
```

As you can see, it is declared as Number, which is correct i think.

When this problem oocurs, if i click on the scrollbar, the 11 interval are correctly redrawn.

Has something solved this problem ?

Comment: Can you when you set the `e.ChartArea.AxisY.Interval ` also set the `...MajorGrid.Interval` ? Also: _if i click on the scrollbar, the 11 interval are correctly redrawn._ where do you click? Is the view changed again or do you just click on the lift without moving it? You could also enforce a `RecalculateAxesScale` on the chartarea.. or simply try the usual suspects: `Refresh()`, `Invalidate()` or `Update()`..

Comment: Hi, i  have tried to add e.ChartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = e.ChartArea.AxisY.Interval but the result is the same. I also have tried RecalculateAxesScale with any effect. But i will try Refresh() and Update() and let you know if there is any improvement. When i click on the scrollbar (on the upper/lower arrow) the chartarea is redrawn with the correct number of interval.